# Prove that for every $f$ in $H$, the sequence $u_n$ which is the projection of $f$ on $K_n$ converges to a limit

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, convex-analysis

$K_n$ is non-increasing sequence of closed convex sets in Hilbert space $H$ such that the intersection of $K_n$ is different from emptiness. Prove that for every $f \in H$, the sequence $u_n$ which is the projection of $f$ on $K_n$ converges to a limit, and identify the limit.

Comment: Apply the identity of the parallelogram in $u_n-f $  and  $f-u_m$

Comment: Write $K=\cap K_n$. Suppose that $P_K$ is the projection associated with $K$ and $P_{K_n}$ is the projection associated with $K_n$. Try to show that $P_{K_n}f\to P_{K}f$.